# Email Attachment File Timestamps

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap

Using Outlook or any other email client, I have noticed that when saving attachment files from emails via IMAP the created and moddified timestamps are set to the timestamp of the operation. Whereas if the account type is Microsoft Exchange then they are the original and correct timestamps of the file.

Moreover, when IMAP, Outlook will not include the seconds either, the timestamp is the current timestamp of the operation rounded down to the minute.

Is this a limitation of the protocol? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I am also able to reproduce similar issue with Outlook365, but what is different is that I could see the seconds normally.

Answer (score -1):

This comment
https://superuser.com/a/1505868/902842
of the topic
[When I send someone a file, are the details (Date created / Date modified / Owner / Computer) sent as well (by default)?](https://superuser.com/questions/309516/when-i-send-someone-a-file-are-the-details-date-created-date-modified-owne?rq=1)
may be the answer.

With Office365/Exchange server, MS Outlook will add timestamp information and read/set them when extract the attachment using "Content-Disposition:" sub-header of the e-mail message data.